# jQuery draggable not working with overflow and Ul elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I've been making a folder and file system and wanted to be able to drag and drop to different folders/ locations.

I have it working where you can drag but I need the overflow on the Ul elements set to hidden because I don't want the scroll bar coming in.

Here is what I am working with: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5Lfsj/7/

HTML:

```
    <main>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="folder">Text Here</li>
      <li class="folder">Text Here</li>
      <li class="folder">Text Here</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="clippet">Text Here</li>
        <li class="clippet">Text Here</li>
      </ul>

      <li class="clippet">Text Here</li>
      <li class="clippet">Text Here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

#menu ul
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".clippet").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    scroll: true,
    delay: 300,
    cursorAt: { left: -5 }
  });

  $(".folder").droppable({
    accept: ".clippet"
  });
```

As you can see when you drag one li element it is not allowed outside of its parent, when dragging them around?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the overflow hidden to the main instead and not menu.

And denying menu to have an overflow with `overflow: none;`